# How to ensure all commands (and errors) handled in order given

Tags: python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio

**TLDR;** How do I make a "single-file" `asyncio.Queue()` and feed it my adb commands, have them executed in the order they're received (one-by-one), handle errors that may occur (disconnect/reconnect) during one of the tasks, and continue processing the rest of the queue after handling the error?

---

I'm working on a module that leverages the existing [python-adb](https://github.com/google/python-adb) module to ultimately control my android tablet as a media device and incorporate it into my home automation setup.

**Problem:**
My module is built entirely around `async`, while the `python-adb` module is not. The `python-adb` module also doesn't manage/throttle requests. And I very quickly found out that if multiple adb commands are requested too quickly the adb connection is overloaded, causing an error & requiring a reconnect whenever the disconnect occurred.

A friend of mine managed to implement a workaround/hack-y solution. **Note:** `self._adb_lock` & `self._adb_error` are initially set in the `AndroidDevice` class's `__init__` function.

```
def adb_wrapper(func):
    """Wait if previous ADB commands haven't finished."""
    @functools.wraps(func)
    async def _adb_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        attempts = 0
        while self._adb_lock and attempts < 5:
            attempts += 1
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
        if (attempts == 4 and self._adb_lock) or self._adb_error:
            try:
                await self.connect()
                self._adb_error = False
            except self._exceptions:
                logging.error('Failed to re-establish the ADB connection; '
                              'will re-attempt in the next update.')
                self._adb = None
                self._adb_lock = False
                self._adb_error = True
                return

        self._adb_lock = True
        try:
            returns = await func(self, *args, **kwargs)
        except self._exceptions:
            returns = None
            logging.error('Failed to execute an ADB command; will attempt to '
                          're-establish the ADB connection in the next update')
            self._adb = None
            self._adb_error = True
        finally:
            self._adb_lock = False

        return returns

    return _adb_wrapper
```

With this workaround I placed the `@adb_wrapper` decorator above all functions that make adb calls. However, this is terribly inefficient & on higher-end devices doesn't prevent overloading of the adb connection.

**Enter asyncio**
Let me start my stating I have very little experience working with `asyncio` at this point; therefore, it's been touch to pick out which questions that were already posted would help me. So, my apologies if the answer is already present elsewhere. Also, in order to give people an idea of how my library is operating the codeblock will be a bit lengthy, but I only included a part of the file (a few functions to show how I'm ultimately interacting) and I tried to only include functions that connect to show the chain of commands.

**My idea of a solution:**
My goal is to be able to use `asyncio` to queue all commands and have them sent one at a time and if at any point the command fails (which would cause adb to disconnect) I want to re-establish the adb connection and continue with the queue of commands.

**Current Code Structure:**

```
class AndroidTV:
    """ Represents an Android TV device. """

    def __init__(self, host, adbkey=''):
        """ Initialize AndroidTV object.
        :param host: Host in format <address>:port.
        :param adbkey: The path to the "adbkey" file
        """
        self.host = host
        self.adbkey = adbkey
        self._adb = None
        self.state = STATE_UNKNOWN
        self.muted = False
        self.device = 'hdmi'
        self.volume = 0.
        self.app_id = None

        self.package_launcher = None
        self.package_settings = None

        self._adb_error = False
        self._adb_lock = False
        self._exceptions = (TypeError, ValueError, AttributeError,
                            InvalidCommandError, InvalidResponseError,
                            InvalidChecksumError, BrokenPipeError)

    @adb_wrapper
    async def connect(self):
        """ Connect to an Android TV device.
        Will attempt to establish ADB connection to the given host.
        Failure sets state to UNKNOWN and disables sending actions.
        """
        try:
            if self.adbkey:
                signer = Signer(self.adbkey)

                # Connect to the device
                self._adb = adb_commands.AdbCommands().ConnectDevice(serial=self.host, rsa_keys=[signer])
            else:
                self._adb = adb_commands.AdbCommands().ConnectDevice(serial=self.host)

            if not self.package_settings:
                self._adb.Shell("am start -a android.settings.SETTINGS")
                await asyncio.sleep(1)
                logging.info("Getting Settings App Package")
                self.package_settings = await self.current_app
            if not self.package_launcher:
                await self.home()
                await asyncio.sleep(1)
                logging.info("Getting Launcher App Package")
                self.package_launcher = await self.current_app

        except socket_error as serr:
            logging.warning("Couldn't connect to host: %s, error: %s", self.host, serr.strerror)

    @adb_wrapper
    async def update(self):
        """ Update the device status. """
        # Check if device is disconnected.
        if not self._adb:
            self.state = STATE_UNKNOWN
            self.app_id = None
        # Check if device is off.
        elif not await self._screen_on:
            self.state = STATE_OFF
            self.app_id = None
        else:
            self.app_id = await self.current_app

            if await self._wake_lock:
                self.state = STATE_PLAYING
            elif self.app_id not in (self.package_launcher, self.package_settings):
                # Check if state was playing on last update
                if self.state == STATE_PLAYING:
                    self.state = STATE_PAUSED
                elif self.state != STATE_PAUSED:
                    self.state = STATE_IDLE
            else:
                # We're on either the launcher or in settings
                self.state = STATE_ON

            # Get information from the audio status.
            audio_output = await self._dump('audio')
            stream_block = re.findall(BLOCK_REGEX, audio_output,
                                      re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)[0]
            self.muted = re.findall(MUTED_REGEX, stream_block,
                                    re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)[0] == 'true'

    @property
    async def current_app(self):
        filtered_dump = await self._dump("window windows", "mCurrentFocus")
        current_focus = filtered_dump.replace("\r", "")
        matches = WINDOW_REGEX.search(current_focus)
        if matches:
            (pkg, activity) = matches.group('package', 'activity')
            return pkg
        else:
            logging.warning("Couldn't get current app, reply was %s", current_focus)
            return None

    @property
    async def _screen_on(self):
        return await self._dump_has('power', 'Display Power', 'state=ON')

    @property
    async def _awake(self):
        return await self._dump_has('power', 'mWakefulness', 'Awake')

    @property
    async def _wake_lock(self):
        return not await self._dump_has('power', 'Locks', 'size=0')

    @adb_wrapper
    async def _input(self, cmd):
        if not self._adb:
            return
        self._adb.Shell('input {0}'.format(cmd))

    @adb_wrapper
    async def _dump(self, service, grep=None):
        if not self._adb:
            return
        if grep:
            return self._adb.Shell('dumpsys {0} | grep "{1}"'.format(service, grep))
        return self._adb.Shell('dumpsys {0}'.format(service))

    async def _dump_has(self, service, grep, search):
        dump_result = await self._dump(service, grep=grep)
        return dump_result.strip().find(search) > -1
```

As I've stated before, the above method partially works, but is basically a band-aid.

The only commands that **directly** make `adb.Shell` calls are
1. `async def connect(self)`
2. `async def update(self)`
3. `async def _input(self, cmd)`
4. `async def _dump(self, service, grep=None)`
5. `async def _key(self, key)`

The `connect` & `update` functions result in multiple `adb.Shell` calls themselves, so this might be where my problem ultimately lies.

**My (3-Part) Question:**
1. How can I queue up all commands as they're received?
2. Execute them in the order they're received?
3. Handle errors at any point, reconnect, then continue executing the rest of the queue of commmands?

## Here's my failed half-attempt at accomplishing this.

```
import asyncio

async def produce_output(queue, commands):
    for command in commands:
        #execute the adb command
        if 'keypress' in command:
            #command contains 'input keypress ENTER'
            adb.Shell(command)
            #mark the task done because there's nothing to process
            queue.task_done()
        else:
            #command contains 'dumpsys audio'
            output = adb.Shell(command)
            #put result in queue
            await queue.put(output)

async def process_adb(queue):
    while True:
        output = await queue.get()
        #return output (somehow?)
        queue.task_done()


async def update():
    adb_queue = asyncio.Queue()
    asyncio.create_task(produce_output(adb_queue,
        [self._screen_on,
         self.current_app,
         self._wake_lock,
         self._dump('audio')]))
    #Not sure how to proceed

    if not self._adb:
        self.state = STATE_UNKNOWN
        self.app_id = None
    # Check if device is off.
    # Fetching result of first item in the queue - self._screen_on
    elif not await adb_queue.get():
        self.state = STATE_OFF
        self.app_id = None
    else:
        # Fetching result of second item in the queue - self.current_app
        self.app_id = await adb_queue.get()

        # Fetching result of third item in the queue - self._wake_lock
        if await adb_queue.get():
            self.state = STATE_PLAYING
        elif self.app_id not in (self.package_launcher, self.package_settings):
            # Check if state was playing on last update
            if self.state == STATE_PLAYING:
                self.state = STATE_PAUSED
            elif self.state != STATE_PAUSED:
                self.state = STATE_IDLE
        else:
            # We're on either the launcher or in settings
            self.state = STATE_ON

        # Get information from the audio status.
        # Fetching result of fourth item in the queue - self._dump('audio')
        audio_output = await adb_queue.get()
        stream_block = re.findall(BLOCK_REGEX, audio_output,
                                  re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)[0]
        self.muted = re.findall(MUTED_REGEX, stream_block,
                                re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)[0] == 'true'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ensure that only a single task is using the `adb` connection to execute a command at any given time. This means you need to either use [synchronisation primitives](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html) to coordinate access, or [use a queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html) to feed a single worker task commands to execute.

Next, because an `adb` connection is entirely *synchronous* and, as with all I/O, relatively *slow*, I'd use a [thread pool executor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#executing-code-in-thread-or-process-pools) to run operations on a `adb` connection off the asyncio loop, so that asyncio is free to run some other tasks that are not currently blocked on I/O. Otherwise, there is no point to putting `.Shell()` commands in a `async def` coroutine, you are not actually cooperating and making room for other tasks to be run.

Last but not least, if even with serialised access to the connection object you find that it can't take too many commands per time period, you would want to use some kind of rate limiting technique. I've [created an asyncio *leaky bucket* algorithm implementation before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45502319/100297) that can take care of this, if so required.

Both a queue or a lock would ensure that commands are executed in first-come-first-serve order, but a queue would require some kind of deferred response mechanism to return command results. A queue would let you queue up related commands (you can add multiple entries using `queue.put_nowait()` without yielding or you can allow grouped commands), without having to wait for a lock first.

Because you want to retry connections, I'd encapsulate the connection object in a [asynchronous context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#asynchronous-context-managers), that can then also handle locking and executing commands with an executor:

```
import asyncio
import collections
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from functools import partial

try:  # Python 3.7
    base = contextlib.AbstractAsyncContextManager
except AttributeError:
    base = object  # type: ignore

_retry_exceptions = (...,)  # define exceptions on which to retry commands?

class asyncnullcontext(base):
    def __init__(self, enter_result=None):
        self.enter_result = enter_result
    async def __aenter__(self):
        return self.enter_result
    async def __aexit__(self, *excinfo):
        pass

class AsyncADBConnection(base):
    def __init__(
        self,
        host,
        adbkey=None,
        rate_limit=None,
        max_retry=None,
        loop=None
    ):
        self._lock = asyncio.Lock(loop=loop)
        self._max_retry = max_retry
        self._loop = None
        self._connection = None
        self._executor = ThreadPoolExecutor()

        self._connect_kwargs = {
            "serial": host,
            "rsa_keys": [Signer(adbkey)] if adbkey else []
        }

        if rate_limit is not None:
            # max commands per second
            self._limiter = AsyncLeakyBucket(rate_limit, 1, loop=loop)
        else:
            self._limiter = asyncnullcontext()

    async def __aenter__(self):
        await self._lock.acquire()
        await self._ensure_connection()
        return self

    async def __aexit__(self):
        self._lock.release()

    async def _ensure_connection(self):
        if self._connection is not None:
            return
        loop = self._loop or asyncio.get_running_loop()
        connector = partial(
            adb_commands.AdbCommands().ConnectDevice,
            **self._connect_kwargs
        )
        fut = loop.run_in_executor(pool, connector)
        self._connection = await fut

    async def shell(self, command):
        loop = self._loop or asyncio.get_running_loop()
        max_attempts = self._max_retry or 1
        attempts = 0
        while True:
            with self._limiter:
                try:
                    fut = loop.run_in_executor(
                        self._executor,
                        self._connection.Shell,
                        command
                    )
                    return await fut
                except _retry_exceptions as e:
                    attempts += 1
                    if attempts >= max_attempts:
                        raise
                    # re-connect on retry
                    self._connection = None
                    await self._ensure_connection()
```

If you then use a queue, use [`Future()` instances](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.Future) to communicate results.

Pushing a job into the queue then becomes:

```
fut = asyncio.Future()
await queue.put((command, fut))
result = await fut
```

You could wrap that into a utility function or object. The `await fut` line only returns once the future has received a result. For commands where you don't care about a result, you only need to `await` if you want to make sure that the command completed.

The consumer in the worker task that manages the connection would use:

```
while True:
    command, fut = await self.queue.get():
    async with self.connection as conn:
        response = await conn.shell(command)
        fut.set_result(response)
    self.queue.task_done()  # optional, only needed when joining the queue
```

where `self.connection` is an `AsyncADBConnection` instance.

Comment: Sounds like exactly what I need. But, could you help me get an idea of how I would do so by providing some code?

Comment: @CaffeinatedCoder: sure, but it'll be generic, not specific to your current codebase. It'll be easy enough to adapt.

Comment: @CaffeinatedCoder: it may be tomorrow before I have time, sorry.

Comment: No worries, whenever you get to it.

Comment: I've tried to create something using the guidelines you laid out, but still having issues since some results require being returned (`dumpsys audio`) and other can immediately be marked `queue.task_done()` (`input keypress 85`). [Here's](https://pastebin.com/AmfQatEm) my attempt.

Comment: @CaffeinatedCoder: I have no Android device, so my code is largely untested, but I've added a context manager that handles the connection and some more queue handling example code.

Comment: Thank you so much for the _very_ descriptive and in-depth answer. I have just one more question. I'm not quite clear on where I should be placing the `while true:` block should be placed. I know that is the block responsible for continually processing commands sent to `AsyncADBConnection`, but where should I place this consumer? I'm not sure what my "worker" task is in my scenerio.

Comment: In a separate task, so in a coroutine you start with [`asyncio.create_task()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task).

Comment: I'll have to play around with this later today and see how I get by. I'll let you know if I get it all working. Thank you so much for all the help :)

Comment: @MartjinPieters I'm still struggling to implement this. Is there somewhere else we can chat, so that you can assist?

Comment: @CaffeinatedCoder: I'll hang around in https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183449/room-for-martijn-pieters-and-caffeinatedcoder a bit. I can't promise what time commitments I can make though.